# Automatic upper case at the beginning of titles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

There are many titles that need improving although the question body itself is fine. This puts people off from editing in case it is considered minor. This then leads to many questions floating around with the upper case letter at the start of the sentence missing.

My proposal:

1. All question titles automatically start with an upper case letter. This provides  a deterrent for minor editors and makes browsing question more pleasant.

If this is too strong of a feature I propose a weaker one:

2. Users under a certain amount of reputation or are known for writing bad titles in the past get automatic title fixing. When the user has sufficient rep this is optional to remove etc.

I cannot imagine a scenario where the title does not need to start with a capital letter. Obvious exceptions may be code or LaTeX so these can be ignored as a title in consideration.

---

Edit:

A suggestion in the comments is to have a pop up telling the question writer that the title does not begin with an upper case letter.

Comment: I'm admittedly a little skeptical that people are able to pull of a flawless body with that kind of mistake in the title, but that's hard to verify.

Comment: @TimStone This is a common problem on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Maybe Shog9 could add   another pop-up warning to complement the [existing all-caps title](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6854/) warning. Something like "please check the spelling and capitalization of your title"...

Comment: This could get real annoying for [titles that start with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856528/jquery-draggble-and-dropable-with-scroll-on-dragable-ul) or anything that [starts with a symbol name / keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612774/stdfunction-as-template-parameter). A warning might be ok though.

Comment: A crappy title with a missing capital letter is still a crappy title with that capital forced in. How do you propose to "ignore LaTeX or code" exactly?

Comment: @Shog9 If the warning is triggered by all-lowercase titles only, jQuery will pass. Keywords are still a problem, though. Maybe test it on some sites that don't have that much code, and trigger only when an all-lowercase title begins with a `[a-z]\s`? This would also pass the titles that begin with $E=mc^2$ or `std:function`.

Comment: @Mat There are plenty examples of uncrappy titles with uncrappy bodies that have that 1 capital letter missing.

Comment: @Alizter: there are also plenty good titles with good questions attached that don't begin with a capital. Plus that sort of error (when it is one) is a very good indicator that the question needs editing - don't bury that signal.

Comment: @Mat Then shall we make it socially acceptable to edit the single letter at the start of the title?

Comment: @Alizter: it already is for people with full edit privileges.

Comment: @Mat In my experience, it was frowned upon to edit just the first letter of a title. Especially if you were bumping an old question.

Comment: @Alizter: if you go on an edit spree just fixing that, then yes, it's frowned upon. If you fix a title when you see one during normal site browsing, it's fine.

Comment: This will really cause havoc on a site like [apple.se], since starting any title with "iPhone", "iPad", "iPod", or "iOS" would be impossible.

Answer (score 4):

The script would require very careful consideration, as there are plenty of scenarios where the initial letter of a sentence being lowercase is *valid*.

And catering for many such scenarios is very time-consuming given the available words in the English language, and then different code languages too.
Devs might end up needing some sort of *whitelist* which is very arduous given the ROI.

---

Main reasons this is not going to make a very big *improvement*:

If the question and subject does not have *more important* issues to resolve than the first word of the subject being capitalised, then an upper case first word subject is neither here nor there as it's otherwise a decent question.

If however the question and/or subject does have other issues, then the first word of the subject being capitalised is probably not an important fix and scripts or human intervention would be better spent elsewhere.

The feature will make *something* better, however I don't see it being particularly important, especially given some of the other feature requests which are ignored/denied etc that would benefit the site(s) more substantially.

---

It might be worth while in some sites, such where there is never any code.  And even then, I would still say just a popup notice to nudge the user.